# Youtube Data API - /channels Endpoint not Returning Smaller Users

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating a networking app for musicians. I was wanting to use the Youtube Data API to let users connect their Youtube channel to their profile within my app. I got everything in place and working via making requests to URLs similar to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&forUsername=PewDiePie&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`. This works great and returns this JSON:

```
{ "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse", "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/bj_rirVFbrVoTIOa6lCGdaXaG5M\"", "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1, "resultsPerPage": 5 }, "items": [ { "kind": "youtube#channel", "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/Blp06js4r7j93y1EfKve84oXWpo\"", "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw", "snippet": { "title": "PewDiePie", "description": "I make videos.", "publishedAt": "2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z", "thumbnails": { "default": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo", "width": 88, "height": 88 }, "medium": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo", "width": 240, "height": 240 }, "high": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo", "width": 800, "height": 800 } }, "localized": { "title": "PewDiePie", "description": "I make videos." }, "country": "US" }, "statistics": { "viewCount": "24334379402", "commentCount": "0", "subscriberCount": "102000000", "hiddenSubscriberCount": false, "videoCount": "4054" } } ] }
```

Most of my app's users will be smaller musicians, likely with less than 10k youtube subscribers. Take my sister for example, this is a link to her youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe4Eogv2uGaKUe4x3VNrwsg.

Whenever trying to search for her Youtube channel with the API via `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&forUsername=Audrey_Chopin&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]` (and variations such as replacing `Audrey_Chopin` with `Audrey%20Chopin` or `Audrey+Chopin`) yield no results: `{ "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse", "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/zJL80hJ0IwMo5wddECFapC8I6Q4\"", "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 0, "resultsPerPage": 5 }, "items": [] }`.

Are smaller users not supposed to be returned from this endpoint? If so, is there any way I can implement users to search for their profile without forcing the user to do the OAuth process, i.e. signing into their Youtube account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the /search endpoint works better for smaller channels, though there is less information available in this endpoint (I am unable to get subscriber count and video count, which was included in the "statistics" part of the /channel endpoint).

So updating

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&forUsername=Audrey_Chopin&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

to

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelType=any&maxResults=50&order=relevance&q=Audrey%20Chopin&type=channel&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

yielded smaller channels, though without as much data as when using the /channel endpoint.

Still curious, if anybody knows, why the /channel endpoint does not return smaller channels.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the user's channel id, simply issue a query to the Channels endpoint on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=...&id=$CHANNEL_ID&key=$APP_KEY`,

and you'll obtain all public (i.e. non-private) info attached to the referenced channel -- without needing any further authentication. Of course you can specify the `part` parameter as you see fit.

On the other hand, please note that querying the [Search.List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint for `snippet` part *is much more costly* than querying the [Channels.List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint for both `snippet` and `statistics` parts: [100 vs. 5](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) quota points.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won’t know the user’s channel ID in this situation; the user is querying to find their own channel (it’s unreasonable to expect lay people to know their channel’s ID). I am familiar that the /channel end point is particularly valuable if you have the channel ID. I’m just curious why the /channel?forUsername endpoint doesn’t return smaller channels.

Comment: Indeed lay people may not know their channel id, but maybe the app that your wrote already has that info. I guess is not much trouble associating users of your app to channel id's, isn't it?

Comment: So, the application does, in fact, add the channel ID to the user's object on the back end, but that is **after** the user has already chosen which channel to associate with their profile. From there, when other users view the user in question's profile, the app will use the channel ID to get the user's channel. Before the channel is set by the user, though, there is no channel ID associated with the user. This question deals with this scenario: the user doesn't have an associated channel yet and wants to query the Youtube Data API to find the right one.